# Why i can not to create an object in the db if i add an relationship belong_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model, this model its a intermediate table

```rb
class CompanyTaskProgress < ApplicationRecord
 include Discard::Model
 belongs_to :task, class_name: 'Tasking::Task'
 belongs_to :progress
end
```

it worked well if i dont add these lines:

```rb
 belongs_to :company_task
 belongs_to :progress
```

this is my Task model

```rb
module Tasking
 class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many : company_task_progresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :progresses, through: : company_task_progresses
 end
end
```

only i am trying to create some object with an iteration:

```rb
ids.each do |id|
   created = CompanyTaskProgress.create(progress_id:, task_id:)
   p 'RESULT',created
end
```

i am getting this object that it has not been created in db

```
'RESULT', #<CompanyTaskProgress id: nil, progress_id: 47, task_id: 1000, discarded_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: you need the plural form `has_many :company_task_progresses` and `has_many :progresses, through: :company_task_progresses`

Comment: @LesNightingill even with that fix its not working well

Comment: @LesNightingill do you need more information? my migration?

Comment: Note in Ruby there is a *huge* difference between `: x` and `:x`.

Comment: suggest you remove `module Tasking` as a wrapper until you get this working

Comment: Is that model stored as `app/models/tasking/task.rb`?

Comment: @tadman yes it is in that route

Comment: What error(s) do you get, if any?

Comment: @tadman i am getting objects like that #<CompanyTaskProgress id: nil,

Comment: That means it failed to save, and you can check with `record.errors.full_messages` It's usually better to use `create!` and `save!` as it's harder to ignore errors.

Comment: @tadman i am getting this error: ["Progress must exist"], but i am sending ids that exist in my db

Comment: Keep an eye trained on `log/developer.log` (like `tail -f`) to see if that ID is resolved properly. Maybe that record doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`belongs_to` associations require the associated record to exist per default, and Ruby on Rails adds validations to ensure that. That means when you add

```
belongs_to :company_task
```

to your model, Rails expects that there will be a `company_task_id` columns on that model's database table, and you cannot create a new record without passing assigning a company_task_id that points to an existing `CompanyTask` record.

Unfortunately, your example is unclear. Note that

```
CompanyTaskProgress.create(progress_id:, task_id:)
```

is a shortcut for

```
CompanyTaskProgress.create(progress_id: process_id, task_id: task_id)
```

But in your example, you iterate over `ids` and pass an `id` to the block. It is unclear where you got the `ids` from that you iterate over. And it is unclear if you set `progress_id` and `task_id` somehow outside the iteration. If you didn't set `progress_id` and `task_id` before the `each` block, then the `CompanyTaskProgress.create(progress_id:, task_id:)` shortcut cannot work because those values will not be assigned correctly.

I suggest changing `create` to `create!` in that method, then you will get an exception with an error message telling what validations failed.

Or you might want to tell Rails that the `belongs_to` association is [`optional`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional) and should not be validated to be present, then change the definition of the association to:

```
belongs_to :company_task, optional: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's not getting saved, but I can tell you how to find out:

`unsaved_object.errors.full_messages`

is going to tell you the validation issues that your object is having.

And if that doesn't do the trick, you could try

`unsaved_object.save!`

which will blow up if it does not save and should spew useful information.  Sometimes there are database issues that don't get recorded to the validation errors as well as you might like.